# bash diff fails to found existing files when providing a path variable containing tilde (~)

Tags: bash, shell, diff, tilde

I have a very surprising problem while trying to execute a `diff` command inside a bash script.

Here is a working code illustrating the point:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd
mkdir foo bar
head -c 1024 /dev/urandom >foo/qux
head -c 1024 /dev/urandom >bar/qux

# works properly as expected
diff ~/{foo,bar}/qux

folder="~"

# this fails with the ~ inside a variable
diff $folder/{foo,bar}/qux

# cleaning the mess
rm -rf foo bar
```

So my question is:

## Why ? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

~ is a feature of shell expansion.
Double quotes limit the expansion to only three features:

1. Command substitution: `$(some command here)` or `` `some command here` ``
2. Variable substitution: `$VAR` or `${VAR}`
3. Arithmetic: `$((2+2))`

so when put inside double quotes, the ~ is not expanded

Comment: This doesn't necessarily explain why `$folder` (unquoted) doesn't expand the tilde.

Comment: What do you mean? Please, give an example.

Answer (score 2):

Don't quote the `~` when assigning it to a variable. The `~` is only expanded by bash when you don't quote it.

Comment: hahahaha :) Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Tilde expansion only applies to unquoted tildes. The tilde must be expanded at the time you perform the assignment to `folder`, because tilde expansion is not applied to parameter expansions, only word splitting and pathname expansion.

```
folder=~  # ~ is expanded, and the result is assigned to folder
```